# django model form multiplechoice change or remove field

Tags: django, django-templates, modelform

I have a model form, and i tried to remove the fields called name, but i cannot.

Here is code:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=MyModel.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
```

The template is very simple:

```
{{form}}
```

On the webpage, it looks like:

name:

(checkbox) ChoiceA

(checkbox) ChoiceB

(checkbox) ChoiceC

I want to remove "name" above, which comes from code in MyForm, But I don't know how to remove it.

If I want to change it to another String, such as "please select the name: ", how to do it?

Comment: I found the solution. use label='' in form

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, while setting the label to `empty` string will work. Ideally you should place this sort of logic in your template. In this example below, I'm looping through the form field and displaying just the field input .

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: If this answer was helpful.. don't forget to accept it as an answer :-)